# Get All users with UserRoleID

Tags: apex-code, soql

I am trying to fetch all users of a role and add their email into a string[] i have some syntax.

```
Error:"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"|0x2f253344
```

My Code.

```
    String[] s;
    for (User a : [Select id,name,email from User where UserRoleId = '00E90000000dffgEAA']) {
        s.add(a.email);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of strings should be initialized by an empty list. It was easy.

```
String[] s = new String[] {};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is giving error, because your soql query is not returning any rows.
You can do something like this to get rid of errors...

```
Integer number_of_rows =  [Select id,name,email from User where UserRoleId = '00E90000000dffgEAA'];
if(number_of_rows>0)
{
    String[] s;
    for (User a : [Select id,name,email from User where UserRoleId = '00E90000000dffgEAA']) {
        s.add(a.email);
    }
}
```